# Current and misplaced switch

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current

I know this is a very noob question, but i just can't help it. Anyways,here is pretty simple circuit [image]

[image]

Now after the circuit is changed this way, why is the current going to be infinitely high??
I hope the question is clear.

Comment: Hi Abdel and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: This is not a homework, i'm practicing for my igcse's, plus i know the answer, but i don't understand why it is so. @JohnRennie

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law

Comment: The resistance is a "brake" that slows down the accelerating electrons. What happens if there is no "brake"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert but I will try to give you reason for your question..

As **Ohm's law** states that the current $I$  through a conductor between two points is directly proportional to the voltage $V$ across the two points with proportionality constant, resistance $R$

Source : [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)

i.e
$$I =\frac{V}{R}$$

in which if voltage $V$ is constant, current $I$ will be inversely proportional to resistance $R$ so if resistance decreases, current will increase i.e
$$I \propto \frac{1}{R}$$

So in your first diagram, putting value in equation  we get :

$$50.10^{-3} =\frac{6}{R} => R = 120 \Omega$$

And in your second diagram, when switch is closed circuit will be **shorted** so circuit resistance $R$ will  approach $0$ (R~0)

$$I =\frac{6}{0} $$

Current $I$ will approch **Infinite** ($I$ ~ undefined)

Comment: Oooh, this makes sense! But what would make us say that the resistance would be almost zero? Like why not 60 or 30 or 50 etc.